# UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'getEncryptedValue()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'get'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj

I was using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.0.3-RELEASE, using pointcut primitive 'get' in my aspect like below.

```
@Pointcut("get(* *) && @annotation(com.test.cryptography.EncryptEnabled)")
    public void getEncryptedValue() {
    }
```

But when I upgrade the spring boot version to 2.6.6 it starts failing with below error.

```
BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException: Pointcut expression 'getEncryptedValue()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'get'
```

Is there any change I need to do for the latest spring release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the Spring manual, chapter [Supported Pointcut Designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators), `get()` is unavailable in Spring AOP. I.e., if it worked for you before, you must have used native AspectJ, possibly via [LTW (load-time weaving)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Therefore, if it is not working anymore after your Spring (Boot) upgrade, you probably just have a configuration issue, maybe something as simple as having forgotten to re-add a JMV parameter `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar`, which probably you were using before.

Comment: Hi Keiegaex, sorry for the delay in response. It worked with load ime weaving, thank you for the suggestion, but I decided to go without this as it is not making much impact to my usecase

Comment: So what did you use instead?

Comment: My usecase is very simple, when user is getting onboarded for the first time, the detials should be encrypted before persisting to the db. it was written using aspects for this usecase, I refactored by not using the aspects. I felt it is not worth to add additional dependency/aspects for single usercase

Comment: I think that not AOP is the problem but rather the way you were using it. You said before that the existing solution before the Spring upgrade was using AOP already, so the simplest way to get it running would have been to find out what was wrong with the config instead of re-implementing it, simply avoiding the problem instead of understanding and solving it. But anyway, I am happy for you that your current solution (which you did not describe, other than saying it is a non-AOP one) is working for you. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway.